# setTimeout won't wait, even when waiting to call a function

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

Started learning javascript yesterday at CodeAcademy and decided I could actually write code. Just kidding. Looked around online, found people with a similar learning curve but none of the answers out there fixed my issue.

In HTML I have 4 divs. 3 live 600px from the left margin. 1 lives 400px from the left margin.

There are also 4 buttons. When I press a button, I'm trying to get the corresponding div to slide to the left over the course of a second until it is left:400px.

I previously had the divs jumping (not taking little steps that looked like sliding) to the correct location but have since broken the code. It seemed like setTimeout wasn't waiting the prescribed time. I did some online research and think that by the time the setTimeout was complete, by margin had already continued to decrease to the final resting place.

```
<html>
<head><title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var stopPositionVisible = 400;
var stopPositionHiding = 200;


function slideIn(xslide){
    slidingDivInNow = document.getElementById(xslide);

    if (parseInt(slidingDivInNow.style.left) > stopPositionVisible ) {
        slidingDivInNow.style.left = parseInt(slidingDivInNow.style.left) - 2 + "px";
        console.log(slidinDivInNow.style.left);
    }

    setTimeout(slideIn(xslide), 20);
}


//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a id="div0link" href="#" onclick="slideIn('d1');">Home</a>
<a id="div1link" href="#" onclick="slideIn('d2');">page1</a>
<a id="div2link" href="#" onclick="slideIn('d3'); ">page2</a>
<a id="div3link" href="#" onclick="slideIn('d4'); ">page3</a>

<div id="d1" style="position:absolute; left:400px; top:50px; background:black; color:white; width:200px">horizontally sliding div</div>
<div id="d2" style="position:absolute; left:600px; top:60px; background:blue; color:white; width:200px">horizontally sliding div</div>
<div id="d3" style="position:absolute; left:600px; top:70px; background:red; color:white; width:200px">horizontally sliding div</div>
<div id="d4" style="position:absolute; left:600px; top:80px; background:green; color:white; width:200px">horizontally sliding div</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any insights.

Comment: 20 milliseconds is almost no time. Not sure what you mean by "the margin had already continued to decrease"; that margin ain't gonna slide itself, you're telling it when and how to.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/xRzXk/

Comment: thank you @mjaric - that is my new favorite website

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
setTimeout(slideIn(xslide), 20);
```

That invokes the `slideIn` function immediately. You aren't passing the `slideIn` function to `setTimeout`, you're passing the value returned by the `slideIn` function. You have to pass a function to `setTimeout`, which means you'd do something like this:

```
setTimeout(slideIn, 20);
```

However, this way, you don't get to pass in the parameter. So you wrap it in an anonymous function like this:

```
setTimeout(function (){
    slideIn(xslide);
}, 20);
```

You could also give the function a name for debugging purposes like this:

```
setTimeout(function slideTimeout(){
    slideIn(xslide);
}, 20);
```

Basically, if you run `typeof` on the first parameter of whatever you're passing to `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, it should return `'function'`. What you're running will return `'undefined'` since you're returning nothing.

Answer (score 3):

put the call in a function container

```
setTimeout(function() { slideIn(xslide); }, 20);
```

Comment: Thank you  @ziesemer  - you guys both gave the answer I 've seen online as best practice.  When I do what is suggested, I'm not seeing any success. The slideIn function does not seem to call itself again, OR it isn't passing the xslide variable back to itself.

Comment: your script is failing at:`console.log(slidinDivInNow.style.left);` correct the spelling to slidingDivInNow and it works gravy in Chrome.  you might want to put a `if (console !== 'undefined') { console.log(...); }` or something so you can test your code in IE, et al...

Answer (score 3):

Your function call within setTimeout is being evaluated immediately.  You want something like this instead, to return a function that will be executed once the timeout elapses:

```
setTimeout(function(){slideIn(xslide)}, 20);
```